# How to write hidden notes in a LaTeX file?

Tags: comments, text-manipulation

How can I write notes in a LaTeX file, that don't appear in the PDF file?

Comment: Is there no way to comment a part of a paragraph? without adding a new line whenever you want to stop the comment

Answer (score 187, accepted):

Smaller text can be marked as comment with the `%` character. TeX ignores everything behind it till the end of the line. (You probably knew that already)

For longer text you can use the `comment` package to define environments which are ignored by LaTeX.

```
\usepackage{comment}
% ...
\begin{comment}
 This text is ignored
\end{comment}
```

If your notes are simple text without any special TeX macros (especially not `\if...` macros) then you can use `\iffalse ... \fi` for this

```
\iffalse
  This text is ignored, but should not include `if...` and `fi` macros
\fi
```

Comment: In fact, the comment package also allows one to define your own comment-like environments. This can be useful to quickly generate two different versions of a document (say, one with and one without answers to exercises). One simply writes `\includecomment{answer}` or `\excludecomment{answer}` in the preamble, and then write each answer in an answer environment.

Answer (score 68):

Of course, you can always use the standard method, placing `%` before each line, to convert  some text into a comment. But if you have tons of comments about contents that at some time you prefer to show in the PDF (for example, in a draft to your thesis supervisor) and you want to distinguish of comments to understand the next piece of LaTeX codes or disable it, then this standard method is not enough.

Here are two approaches to easily hide/unhide another type of comments:

**Hide all comments (those without `%`)**.

1. Define in the preamble a new command (wasting imagination I thought in `\comment`) that simply do nothing (see the MWE). Then you can use safely  comments as `\comment{`*The boss is too stupid to understand this paragraph,  write it with simple words.*`}`
2. Use the `todonotes` package with the option `disable`.

**Unhide comments**

1. Disable the new command `\comment` in the preamble (with as `%` before) and define again to show their content (better with some different format that the body text).
2. In `todonotes` package remove the option `disable`. Bonus advantage: a pretty to-do list.

I hope that both approaches are self-explained in this MWE:

[image: MWE]

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \usepackage{lipsum} % dummy text for the MWE

% Put % before of what you want disabled

% Select what to do with todonotes: 
% \usepackage[disable]{todonotes} % notes not showed
\usepackage[draft]{todonotes}   % notes showed

% Select what to do with command \comment:  
% \newcommand{\comment}[1]{}  %comment not showed
\newcommand{\comment}[1]
{\par {\bfseries \color{blue} #1 \par}} %comment showed


\begin{document}
\lipsum[1] 
\todo{This is a to do note at margin}
\lipsum[2] 
\comment{This is a simple comment between text} 
\lipsum[3]
\todo[inline]{This is a todo note inline} 
\comment{This is the end, check the to-do list}
\listoftodos
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd never heard of todonotes before, thanks for that!

Comment: Just a note that this package is a performance trojan horse. Had to remove it from one of my projects due to high compile time.

Comment: @Jerry This example in my computer is compiled  roughly in 0.35 second. Of these, only 0.19 seconds are due to todonotes. Tikz-based solutions as well as other complex packages  always has this disadvantage but depend of the project/machine if this is serious.  The issue is if the delay is  enough to allow yourself a coffee while you wait, or only to stress you.

Comment: @Fran I use Overleaf and they provide me 1 minute of compile time before it times out (in the free version). I removed the package and never experienced a timeout even though I had a dozen eps files. I use overleaf since it provides real-time collaboration between peers. So, in this case todonotes was a performance trojan.

Comment: In order to avoid unwanted consecutive blank spaces I would define the variant for not showing the comment as `\newcommand\comment[1]{\@bsphack\@esphack}`.

Answer (score 23):

If I understand your question correct, use a `%` at the beginning of the line. The percentage sign indicates a comment, which is text that isn't typeset.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
This text will be in the PDF.
% This is a comment, and will not appear.
\end{document}
```

To print a percentage sign in the text, use `\%`.

Answer (score 20):

A solution I use is the following: I defined a command to write my comments in:

```
\newcommand{\rood}[1]{\textcolor{red}{[#1]}} %for displaying red texts
```

("rood" is Dutch for "red"). A comment looks like this:

```
\rood{This comment is displayed in red}
```

When I want to create my final version, I simply remove the second part of this comment, meaning that all text simply is not displayed:

```
\newcommand{\rood}[1]{} %for displaying red texts
```

Apart from the package for displaying the color (`xcolor`), no other packages are necessary!

Comment: with one CAVEAT though (I think): make sure you only have a single space **either** before **or** after the comment, ***not*** both, else you'll end up with extra gaps when using `\newcommand{\rood}[1]{}` before going to press... correct me if I'm wrong, I'm a beginner!

Comment: Yes, that seems to be true. When I create a PDF from my code the way you describe, it seems a "double-width" space is put in, i.e. it looks like two spaces (which is undesired), but copy-pasting the PDF text into a text editor only copies one space. Also **watch out with no spaces** before and after!

Comment: I do something similar, without `todonotes` too, defining `\comment` as `\marginpar{\parbox{...}{#1}}` and to hide just comment the definition out: `%\marginpar{\parbox{...}{#1}}`

Comment: I tested `\newcommand{\rood}[1]{\ignorespaces}` and it seems to correct the problem of two spaces.

Comment: `\newcommand{\rood}[1]{\@bsphack\@esphack}` corrects the problem of two spaces.

Answer (score 13):

You could use the `fixme` package if you want to make comments in the pdf-file that you can turn on or off.

The package can be found here: http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fixme.

You can implement it by putting something like this in your preamble:

```
\usepackage[draft]{fixme}
\fxsetup{layout=footnote, marginclue}
```

You then make a comment in the text by using `\fxnote{...}`. If you put in `final` instead of `draft` your comments will not be visible in the pdf-file.

You can get a list of all the notes by using the command `\listoffixmes`. This is the most simple use of `fixme` but it offers loads of other possibilities like annotations and highlighting of the text.

Answer (score 4):

Anything after `\end{document}` will be completely ignored by the compiler and doesn't need any comment environment. It won't end up in the output file, as well.

Comment: +1 an easy and effective way to keep "bulk" blocks together with the document without cluttering it. I use this technique frequently to keep for a while all those paragraphs or complete chapters I delete or have to rewrite.

Comment: I often place a second `\end{document}` earlier in the text to just typeset the part before it.

Answer (score 2):

I've been using this simple verbatim solution for longer notes:

```
% Use `todos' as environment for large lists verbatim-printed. Use fancyvrb
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{todos}
 {Verbatim}
 {fontsize=\footnotesize,formatcom=\color{blue}}

% Uncomment to remove the notes from PDF. Use the comment package
%\excludecomment{todos}
```

## Example

```
\begin{todos}
- Proofread for minor typos
- Include missing references
   - Enable all latex warnings
   - Search Google Scholar for Bibtex entries
\end{todos}
```

[image]

## Pro

- You can write down quick notes freely without caring about formatting, itemizing, etc.

## Cons

- Not convenient for formatting actual text that might go into the manuscript: no automatic line breaking, etc.
- No list of notes generation (I never use this anyways)