# A flag to switch between simple and full mode

Tags: environments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to write hidden notes in a LaTeX file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11177/how-to-write-hidden-notes-in-a-latex-file)
>   [Conditional typesetting / build](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33576/conditional-typesetting-build)

Is it possible to add a flag (variable) in my `.tex` file, so that I can switch among two modes: a light version and a full version?

The text which is supposed to be displayed in full mode could be wrapped in an environment:

```
... flag ...
\begin{fullmode}
...
\end{fullmode}
```

So when `flag` is 0, the text wrapped in `fullmode` is hidden in the pdf file generated; while `flag` is 1, the text wrapped in `fullmode` is displayed ...

Does anyone know how to realize that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [versions](http://ctan.org/pkg/versions) package and use the commands `\includeversion{fullmode}` or `\excludeversions{fullmode}` in the preamble as your flag.