# A macro dependent on a parameter

Tags: macros

I would like to write a macro `privatecomment` whose behaviour depends on a global parameter `show`.

For example, in the `.tex`, I could write `\privatecomment{Here is a comment}`. When I set `show` to `true`, it prints `Here is a comment` in `.pdf`; otherwise, it prints nothing.

Could anyone tell me how to realise that?

Comment: Did you see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11177/how-to-write-hidden-notes-in-a-latex-file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do

```
\newif\ifshow
\showtrue
\def\privatecomment#1{\ifshow#1\fi}
```

but really it's simpler and more efficient to do

```
\def\showtrue{\def\privatecomment##1{##1}}
\def\showfalse{\def\privatecomment##1{}}
\showtrue
```

Answer (score 5):

A simple if switch without any frillz.

```
\documentclass{article}  
\newif\ifshowmycomments
\showmycommentstrue
\long\def\privatecomment#1{\ifshowmycomments#1\fi}
\begin{document}  
\privatecomment{Shows by default}
\showmycommentsfalse

\privatecomment{Turned off}
\showmycommentstrue

\privatecomment{On again.}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

A proper way is to use `\@bsphack` and `\@esphack`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newif\ifshowprivatecomments
\showprivatecommentstrue
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\privatecomment}[1]{%
  \ifshowprivatecomments
    \textcolor{red!50}{#1}%
  \else
    \@bsphack\@esphack
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}  

This is text \privatecomment{This is a comment}
and the text continues.

\privatecomment{A comment between paragraphs}

Some text again.

\showprivatecommentsfalse

This is text \privatecomment{This is a comment}
and the text continues.

\privatecomment{A comment between paragraphs}

Some text again.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This nicely eliminates whitespace, but not if `this \privatvecomment{stuff}!` and `\showprivatecommentfalse`.  This results in `this !`.  Is there a workaround for that?

Comment: @A.Ellett There should be no space before `\privatecomment` in this case, as the `!` immediately follows `this`.

Comment: That's not what happened when I tested it.  I had to add `\unskip`.

Answer (score 1):

In the documents for my classes, I set lots of flags to either show answer or hide answers, to create a slightly different version of the document, for all sorts of purposes.  I generally don't like having to go into the document and change something to create these modifications.  Instead, I create a directory I call `./.design` in which I place various files whose existence (or lack thereof) determines which modifications take effect.

My answer is here is about how to build an interface at the command line to facilitate changing how the file gets compiled.  The other answers show you how to implement those changes once they've been made.

So for example, I might have the following files in my `./.design` directory:

```
show_answers.true
two_column_doc.false
compile_practice_version.false
```

That way, at a glance I can see how I've set up the document.  I've also created a perl script that allows me to easily toggle or change these settings (for my private purposes not all of them are binary).

For your command, here's an approach to you question following my idea.

First some perl code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict 'vars';
&MAIN(@ARGV);
sub MAIN {
   my $fh_true  = "./.design/show_comment.true";
   my $fh_false = "./.design/show_comment.false";
   if ( -e $fh_true )
     {
       system("mv $fh_true $fh_false");
     }
   elsif ( -e $fh_false )
     {
       system("mv $fh_false $fh_true");
     }
   else
     {
       system ("touch $fh_true");
     }
}
```

The perl code can be called from the command line.  It does one of two things, it either toggles the name of the file between `./.design/show_comment.true` and `./.design/show_comment.false` **or**, if neither file exists, it creates `./.design/show_comment.true` as a default value.  All levels of complexity can be added to such a perl script.

And then the document you wish to create can be written as

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\privatecomment[1]{%%
  \IfFileExists{./.design/show_comment.true}
    {``#1''}
    {\unskip\@bsphack\@esphack}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

  Hello \privatecomment{world} and more stuff.

\end{document}
```

Here's the result when `./.design/show_comment.true` has been created:

[image]

There are some problems with this particular definition.  When `./.design/show_comment.true` does not exist we get the following result:

[image]