# Comment without dropping characters

Tags: comments

I am interested if there is a way to do a comment in this way?
[image]

Comment: you can always move `\(\lrangle` to the next line (and comment using that environment or a simple ``%`

Comment: `\iffalse...\fi` also works in certain situations, see for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11177/how-to-write-hidden-notes-in-a-latex-file.